# AJPProxyを使用しコンテキストパスを/にすると、css/js等の相対パスがうまく読み込めない

Tags: java, apache, spring, tomcat

環境は
java8
Tomcat8
SpringMVC
です。

WEBアプリケーションを作成したさい、VIEWのスタイルシート、JavaScriptの相対パスがずれる対策についてです。

コンテキストパスを、"/"にし、
[http://ドメイン/](http://%E3%83%89%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3/)
でTOPページにアクセスするようにしたいのですが、
server.xmlにDocBaseを書かないと、

```
http://ドメイン/コンテキストパス/
```

にしないとつながらないと思います。
そのため、apacheのAJPプロキシをつかって、

```
http://ドメイン/
```

を

```
http://ドメイン:8080/コンテキストパス
```

に転送するようにしましたが、
取り込むjs, cssのパスが

```
http://ドメイン/js/~~~.js
```

とか、

```
http://ドメイン/css/~~~.css
```

になってしまい、うまく取り込めません。

しぶしぶserver.xmlにDocBaseを追記し、
コンテキストパスを/にしました。
ほかに稼働サーバーに依存しないいい設定方法はないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

Apacheのhttpd.confないしはproxy_ajpの設定にて

```
<IfModule proxy_ajp_module>
  <Location / >
    ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8009/warのコンテキストパス/
  </Location>
</IfModule>
```

を記載すれば大丈夫かと存じます。
ポイントはLocationがルートパス(/)→Tomcatのwarのコンテキストパスを指定しているところです。

もちろん、Webアプリケーション側のcss/jsのパスの記述にコンテキストパスなど記載しているとマズいですが。

参考になれば幸いです

Comment: 質問時点でそのような記述をしていました。
そのため全てのviewは/でアクセスできましたが、
css,js等は読み込めませんでした。
読み込もうとした外部ファイルのURLが
ドメイン/css/main.css
となっていたため、これらのファイルはajp転送出来ていなかったものと思います。

Comment: 質問の中にある

「取り込むjs, cssのパスが

http://ドメイン/js/~~~.js
とか、

http://ドメイン/css/~~~.css
になってしまい、うまく取り込めません。」

とありますので、ご自分でJSPに記述されたということでしょうか。それともwarファイル内にcssやjsがあるということでしょうか。

もしwarファイル内にあるcssやjsを使わない場合はApache httpdのhtdocs以下に想定されるパス構成で配置すればよいだけです。

Comment: css,jsはwar内部にあります。
デプロイ時のパスは
「　tomcat/webapps/WEB-INF/css/　」等です。
同じWEB-INF内にある「view/index.jsp」は、AJP転送で「http://ドメイン/」につながりますが、viewから取り込んでいる「 css/main.css」等はAJP転送されているものの、実際の配置先が「 http://ドメイン/コンテキストパス/css/main.css 」になっているため、NOT FOUNDになってしまうということです。

Comment: cssの設定は、SpringMVCのresource定義で <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/WEB-INF/css/" /> で、WEB-INF/cssの内容を設定している感じでしょうか。JSPに記載されているパスの設定と、SpringMVCのリソース設定を確認してみてください。こちらなどが参考になるかと思います。http://bookmount8.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-5.html